# Angular 7 - When user types in input field, how can I make the actual value upper case?

Tags: validation, angular7, uppercase

Currently, when the user is typing in an input field, I have a css property that will transform the text to uppercase.  I've run into a few problems however with validation.

For example, if a user is asked to confirm their email address and they copy and paste the value in one field to the next, it is telling them that the emails do not match.

My suspicion is that the actual value typed in is lowercase and the value they paste into the confirmation input is uppercase and therefore do not match (i could be wrong but thats not what I am trying to resolve at this time.

How can I make a text input field value all uppercase, as the user types using only angular 7?

My css file contains:

```
.make-uppercase {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

My HTML for the email field is as follows:

```
              <div class="col-lg-8 registration-answer">
               <label for="form-student-contact-3" class="col-lg-12" data-hint="yes">
                <span class="form-required">*</span>{{'Confirm Email Address' | translate}}<i class="fa fa-info-circle ml-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              formControlName="confirmEmail"
              [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && registerFormControl.confirmEmail.errors }"
              class="form-control make-uppercase col-md-8"
              data-hint="yes"
              id="form-student-contact-text-3"
            >
            <div  *ngIf="registerFormControl.confirmEmail.errors" class="text-danger col-md-8">
              <div *ngIf="this.registerFormControl.confirmEmail.touched && this.registerFormControl.confirmEmail.invalid && !this.registerFormControl.confirmEmail.errors.required">
                  Emails do not match.
              </div>

              <div *ngIf="registerFormControl.confirmEmail.errors.required" class="text-danger col-md-8">
                  Confirm Email is required.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

In my TS file for my reactive form

```
  ngOnInit() {
this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  email: ['', Validators.required],
  confirmEmail: ['', Validators.required],
}, {
    validator: CustomValidators.MustMatch('email', 'confirmEmail')
  });
```

And my custom validator for MustMatch

```
  static MustMatch(controlName: string, matchingControlName: string) {
return (formGroup: FormGroup) => {
  const control = formGroup.controls[controlName];
  const matchingControl = formGroup.controls[matchingControlName];

  if (matchingControl.errors && !matchingControl.errors.mustMatch) {
    // return if another validator has already found an error on the matchingControl
    return;
  }

  // set error on matchingControl if validation fails
  if (control.value !== matchingControl.value) {
    matchingControl.setErrors({ mustMatch: true });
  } else {
    matchingControl.setErrors(null);
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching around I found an answer in case anyone was wondering.

Add this to the input property:

```
oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()"
```

Keep the CSS text transform to prevent the user from seeing lowercase letters being transformed into uppercase:

```
.make-uppercase {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```